# What is the distribution of $d'$?

Tags: distributions, anova, signal-detection

In my experiment, repeated measures of $d'$ (computed from hit and false alarm rates) are computed for a small number of subjects (<10) under multiple (10) conditions. Primarily, I am interested to see if any of the 9 out of 10 conditions differ from the control condition.

I am wondering if I am supposed to use a non-parametric method such as Friedman's test, or if I should assume normality for $d'$ and use one-way repeated measures ANOVA.

From the limited sources I could find, I understand that $d'$ often is treated as essentially normal<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1. Kaplan, A. (2009). A Comparison of Three Methods for Calculating
Confidence Intervals around D-Prime. ([pdf](http://home.utah.edu/~u0703432/CV/phons09.pdf))</sub>

Comment: It depends on your subjects. If half have very high d's and half have very low then the distribution will be far from normal.  You might consider Dunnett's test for the comparisons.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the d's and observing their actual distribution?